# Нужна ли высшая математика в веб-программировании?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, canvas, математика, геометрия

Я понимаю, что она нужна например при разработке трёхмерных игр и т.п. А если я решу заняться двумерной графикой, мне необходимо изучить высшую математику и геометрию, или не обязательно?

Уровень моих знаний по математике пока равен почти нулю. По геометрии — так же.

Эти предметы я плохо понимал в школе. Сейчас собираюсь подучить. На русском простых и понятных книг по математике не нашёл (если не считать детские книжки) — нашёл несколько хороших книг на английском, вот сижу изучаю.

Comment: Я правда не знаю, сколько вам лет, но, как человек, сдавший ГОСы по 5-ти предметам из Высшей математики, говорю: "НАФИГ НЕ НУЖНА". Ибо знание Функционального Анализа и Уравнений Математической Физики в программировании не нужно. Если будет что-то надо - выучите.

Comment: Мне 30. Образование гуманитарное - английский язык.

Comment: Собственно, тогда все просто. Изучайте книги(те, которые нашли), пробуйте применять знания на практике. Знать именно "Высшую Математику" для работы с графикой не надо абсолютно точно, ибо вы не знаете, что такое Высшая математика :)). Что-то конечно придется подучить. Сам я особенно графикой не занимался и не могу сказать точнее, может вот кто ответит. Но ВМ точно не нужна, скорее всего понадобятся базовые знания, а не ВМ.

Comment: Я могу посоветовать [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/). Школьная программа и начала высшей математики - вполне себе доступно. Так-то вроде не нужна, но "математику уже затем учить следует, что она ум в порядок приводит"

Comment: > Ибо знание Функционального Анализа и Уравнений Математической Физики в программировании не нужно.

Ну что тут скажешь - я бы вас в команду не взял.

Comment: > "математику уже затем учить следует, что она ум в порядок приводит"

Согласен на 146%

Comment: @northerner - если не затруднит, приведите пожалуйста пример где, по вашему, никак не обойтись без знаний высшей математики в веб-программировании.

И объясните пожалуйста - почему вы бы не взяли человека без знаний высшей математики, неужели это настолько важно в вебе?

Сейчас-же я не вижу вообще никаких обоснований, просто слова...

PS: сам я математику уважаю, но к вопросу это не имеет отношения

Comment: Поясните что такое «*веб*-программирование.»

Если это которое клепание формочек на джанге с рельсами, проектирование сверхбыстрых распределенных масштабируемых NoSQL API на node.js, да верстка progressive-enhanced mobile first responsive web страничек — то, нет, не нужна там математика. Арифметика от силы.

Comment: Собственно я об этом и толкую...

Comment: вот допустим статья [Как правильно сортировать контент на основе оценок пользователей](http://habrahabr.ru/post/143188/), в ней говориться, что самый правильный рейтинг = Нижняя граница доверительного интервала Вильсона (Wilson) для параметра Бернулли, тривиальная задача создания рейтинга, а сколько в ней всякого матана

Comment: @Spectre: Веб-погромисту для этого ничего знать не нужно. Ему нужно прочитать хабрастатью, лайкнуть, ретвитнуть и скопипастить формулу.

Comment: @Olter, вы неправы, говоря что:

> знание Функционального Анализа и Уравнений Математической Физики в программировании не нужно

Я лично напоролся на это в конце апреля, читая совершенно прикладную книгу, где автор, переходя от простого к сложному, непринужденно перешел от громоздких арифметических формул к **сверткам**, что вынудило меня отложить книгу и <strike>полезть за козлом</strike> восполнить пробелы в функциональном анализе, прежде чем я смог усвоить очередной параграф (параграф, не главу!).

@drdaeman, БД - это не арифметика, а теория множеств и реляционная алгебра, кстати :-)

Comment: @drdaeman, это если предположить, что для любой тривиальной задачи есть более эффективное решение с помощью матана, о котором уже есть статья на хабре

Comment: Я, наверное, зря `<sarcasm>` не указал.

*Веб*-погромист это как «фотограф передних планов» или даже «пекарь верхушек тортов.»

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обязательно нужны базовые знания и умение их применять. Даже просто найти нужную формулу и подставить в нее нужные значения иногда требует понимания, что происходит.
И всей высшей математики пригодится только небольшая часть.
Для 2d графики в различных задачах при работе с графическими примитивами (определение расстояния, положения, определение области касания, области пересечения) пригождается **аналитическая геометрия**. Грубо говоря, дюжина основных формул. Такие например, как уравнение прямой, расстояние от точки до прямой и др. Это не требует даже особых знаний математики. Нашел формулу, подставил цифры нужные, получил результат. Но нужно понимать, что в этих формулах из себя представляет та или иная переменная.
И очень хорошо бы понимать **основы дискретной математики**. Эта наука для программиста гораздо значительней. Оттуда можно взять достаточно много. Хотя как показывает мой опыт, можно и без неё обходится, но при этом придется самому придумывать, то что уже описано в дискретке. Так что чтобы быть эффективным нужно и там покопаться. Это может сэкономить в будущем кучу времени. Особенно, что касается графов.

Comment: Дискретная математика - едва ли не единственная вещь из ВМ, которая с большой вероятностью пригодится программисту. :)

Comment: Ну прямо единственная. Еще есть мат. статистика — это вообще широчайшее применение, та же работа со временными рядами встречается даже в гостевухах и дейтенгах. И, как минимум, преобразования Фурье, вейвлеты, DCT и иже с ними, это, ЕМНИП, функциональный анализ — оно надо при любой обработке сигналов.

Answer (score 13):

Математику уже затем учить следует, что она ум в порядок приводит © Ломоносов М.
По существу, если именно веб-программирование, то и школьная не особо пригодится.
Если уж решили что-то подучить в плане теории, то лучше взяться за дискретную математику (например, хотя-бы Р. Хаггарти "Дискретная математика для программистов").
Также по алгоритмам рекомендую почитать что-нибудь.
По-поводу аналитической геометрии и т. п., я думаю, достаточно будет взять простой справочник. Мне, например, справочник Выгодского М. Я. очень нравится (справочник Бронштейна Семендяева тоже неплох)

Answer (score 5):

Вопрос неконкретный. Веб-программирование - широкое понятие. Математика - еще более широкое понятие. Какие-то разделы математики не потребуются, а какие-то - потребуются. Типичное приложение для веба включает работу с базами данных SQL, которые построены на реляционной алгебре, которая прямо относится к математике (разделы алгебры). Ну и вообще программирование динамичных страниц подразумевает работу с JavaScript, что близко к написанию функций (разделы анализа).

Comment: Подозреваю, что подавляющее большинство программистов на SQL не задумываются, что используют опрерацию *проекция* из РА, когда они перечисляют имена столбцов таблицы в запросе select ...

Answer (score 0):

Математику приходится знать. И обязательно надо знать хотя бы базовую часть в рамках первых двух курсов института. Мне как-то выпало в жизни узнать очень много статистики и, поскольку я системно занимался автоматическим обучением, пришлось много учить специализированной математики. В целом если ты не знаешь математики в рамках школьно-институтского курса, то жизнь программиста тебе не очень понравится.
Математика(алгебра) в первую очередь развивает логику, а без логики никуда.